unexpected behavior of glossary-extra, acronyms are counted starting from lof/lot
I'm experiencing a weird (I presume) behavior for the package glossary-extra. Basically, as you can see in the MWE below, I have some glossary items as well as acronyms. I've also added some code, as the developer suggested, to toggle a link only for the first appearance of a term/acronym.
However, I just realized that in my LOF (I assume would be the same in the LOT) once I used the acronym SNPs INDELs and PCA the count starts there and the in-text — at page 6 — occurrences are disabled... I'm pointing out this as for another figure where I have a glossary term which is in the short caption of my LOF this does not happen.
Is there a way to fix it? Thanks in advance!
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[inkscapearea=page]{svg}
\usepackage[postdot,acronym,toc]{glossaries-extra}
%\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries} % standard glossary

%GLOSSARY TERMS AND ACRONYMS
\makeglossaries
\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{Page: }{Pages: }
\GlsXtrEnableLinkCounting{general,acronym}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\makefirstuc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\acrshort}[1][]{\glsxtrshort[#1]}
\renewcommand*{\acrshortpl}[1][]{\glsxtrshortpl[#1]}
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\color{black}{#1}}
% disable hyperlink if link count is greater than 1:
\renewcommand*{\glslinkpresetkeys}{%
 \ifnum\GlsXtrLinkCounterValue{\glslabel}>1
  \setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}%
 \fi
}

%EXAMPLE TERMS
\newglossaryentry{graph-topology}
{
    name=topology,
    description={collection of features and properties describing a graph data structure}
}

\newacronym{pca}{PCA}{Principal Component Analysis}
\newacronym{hifi}{HiFi}{High Fidelity, same as CCS}
\newacronym{grch38}{GRCh38}{Genome Reference Consortium human Build 38}
\newacronym{snp}{SNP}{Single Nucleotide Polymorphism}
\newacronym{snv}{SNV}{Single Nucleotide Variant, same concept of SNP when working with a single sample instead of a panel}
\newacronym{indel}{INDEL}{INsertion-DELetion up to 49 base pairs}
\newacronym{sv}{SV}{Structural Variant}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
    \listoffigures
\end{center}
\newpage

\chapter{Introduction}

The assemblies for these individuals were generated from \acrshort{hifi} long reads in combination with long-range contact information from parental data through trio binning <citation> of short reads. Beyond the purpose of the text above, I'm using here the \gls{graph-topology} terms which since it has been used only once, it appears in the Terminology section.

\chapter{Results}

I computed the following assembly statistics for individuals: HG002, HG00514, HG00733, HG03492 and NA19240 with \texttt{gfastats v1.3.0} <citation> as per \dots. Aside from individual HG002 with a \acrshort{hifi} coverage in folds of $\sim$130× and sequenced with a 20Kbp \acrshort{hifi} chemistry, other individuals show values in line with those of assemblies, produced from long reads \acrshort{hifi} data and long-range Hi-C contact information, which did not underwent ulterior polishing and curation. The average coverage for the \acrshort{hifi} datasets varied from a maximum of $\sim$76× to a minimum of $\sim$34×.

As in the previous chapter, I'm here using the \gls{graph-topology} terms which appears to have the same issue despite the settings used in the preamble.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=6.5in]{example-image}
\caption[\textbf{\texttt{minigraph-CATUS} and \texttt{PGGB} variant calling performance evaluation}]{\textbf{\texttt{minigraph-CATUS} and \texttt{PGGB} variant calling performance evaluation.} Comparison of \texttt{PGGB} and \texttt{minigraph-CACTUS} variant calling performance; both graphs were evaluated using the three standard metrics of precision, recall and F1. \acrshortpl{snv} and \acrshortpl{indel}, jointly referred to as small variants in-text, were called with \texttt{Deep Variant}, whereas structural variants were genotyped with \texttt{PanGenie}. For both variant types \acrshort{grch38} was used as reference.} \label{figure:mg-CACTUS_vs_PGGB}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\section{Exploratory population genetics analyses}

\dots more rsults \dots

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=6.5in]{example-image}
\caption[\textbf{\acrshort{pca} scatter-plots for \acrshortpl{snp} and \acrshortpl{indel}}]{\textbf{\acrshort{pca} scatter-plots for \acrshortpl{snp} and \acrshortpl{indel}.} \dots} \label{figure:pcas}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\printglossary[title=Terminology, toctitle=Terminology]

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=List of Abbreviations, toctitle=List of Abbreviations]

\end{document}

